# Saving multiple attachments and retriving them

Tags: php, javascript, upload, phpmyadmin

I have a simple html form, that sends a Email, with multiple attachments (max of 5). I am saving the Email messages, Address in phpadmin. Now i want to save the multiple attachments also. 
How can i save multiple attachments, and then retrive then back on an other page.

I am using phpmailer to send Email and attachments, The loop for sending attachments is:

```
  $MyUploads = array();
  foreach(array_keys($_FILES['attach']['name']) as $key) 
{  
$filesize = $_FILES['attach']['size'][$key];
$extention = pathinfo ($_FILES['attach']['name'][$key] ,PATHINFO_EXTENSION );
$name=$_FILES['attach']['name'][$key];
    $filePath = $Location . $name;
    $tmpName = $_FILES['attach']['tmp_name'][$key];


if(move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $filePath))
    {$MyUploads[] = $Location;}
     else
    {$MyUploads[]='';}
     print_r($MyUploads);


$source = $_FILES['attach']['tmp_name'][$key];
$filename = $_FILES['attach']['name'][$key];
$mail->AddAttachment($source, $filename);

}
```

And the query for inserting these files location in to database is

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO upload (name, type, size, file1, file2, file3, file4, file5,
    created) VALUES  
            ( 
            '".$name."',  
            '".$extention."',  
            '".$filesize."',  
            '".$MyUploads[0]."',  
            '".$MyUploads[1]."',  
            '".$MyUploads[2]."',  
            '".$MyUploads[3]."',
    '".$MyUploads[4]."' ,
    now() 
            )"; 
      $result = $dbLink->query($insert);
```

please now how can i retrive these files on another php page. Please  i am a beginner so any toturial.

Comment: Related: [retrieving images from database and displaying all on a page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10196929/retrieving-images-from-database-and-displaying-all-on-a-page)

Answer (score 2):

This has been answered here multiple times .. please see

[multi image upload wrong quantity on file-upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10170277/multi-image-upload-wrong-quantity-on-file-upload/10170975#10170975)

[limiting the checking condition while uploading swf files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10151960/limiting-the-checking-condition-while-uploading-swf-files/10152156#10152156)

**EDIT 1**

What i think your table should be like

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `upload` (
  `uploadID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uploadExt` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `uploadSize` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `uploadPath` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `uploadName` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`uploadID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

How to Insert

```
$mysql = new mysqli("localhost","root","","test");
$sql = "INSERT INTO `upload` (
`uploadID` ,
`uploadExt` ,
`uploadSize` ,
`uploadPath` ,
`uploadName`
)
VALUES (
NULL ,  '%s',  '%s',  '%s',  '%s');"


foreach($image_you_have_uploaded as $valid) /// Am sure you know what this is 
{
    //Make sure you mysql_real_escape_string everthing 
    $mysql->query(sprintf($sql,$extention,$filesize,$filePath,$name));
}
```

How to get the images

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM upload WHERE uploadName = '%s'" ;
$result = $mysql->query(sprintf($sql,mysql_real_escape_string($name)));

var_dump($result->fetch_assoc())// Output Result
```

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you, I have edited my question, after making the changes u said. Please would u specify on what can i do to retrieve them now

Comment: I don't agree to how you are inserting your images .. i would update with what i think its the best solution .. hold on